# visual studio 2010, how to open a rtf (word or any other format like) inside the IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rtf

Exists one add-ins or one way for **open and edit** rtf files **inside** visual studio 2010?.

I tried searching for an add-ins without a luck.

Also, clicking in rtf, it opens as a text file, for example

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang13322{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}} 
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue0;\red255\green221\blue187;\red255\green242\blue230;\red200\green221\blue187;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs22 originaltext}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Use Word, Write or Open Office.

Comment: i tried this and even with File/Open in VS, it opened wordpad outside of VS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to double click the file in Solution Explorer and have it open in another editor, you can right click, select Open With..., and choose another program.

Comment: but it is opening outside visual studio, not inside.

Comment: ?. Visual studio is not a code editor but a whole ide, including access to database, html edition and so on.sheesh.

Comment: I too would like to have an add-on to be able to use basic RTF documents from _inside the VS 2010...